# Horizontal scrolling in Sencha Touch2 list

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

[image]I have a list with the following config,

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            scrollable: {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            directionLock: true
        },

    store: compStore,
    itemTpl: '<table width="2000px">
<tr><td width="500px" style="border 1px solid black">{company}</td>
<td width="200px">{price}</td>
<td width="200px">{change}</td>
<td width="200px">{pct}</td>
<td width="200px">{updated}</td>
</tr></table>'

    });
```

I am able to see only the first 3 fields on the screen(they are: company,price,change), the rest of list columns i am not able to see since the table is too big to fit in into the view space.

When i scroll the list(horizontally) i can see the other fields but after releasing, it again disappears.

As you can see in the attached image, the list is displaying only some of the columns, im unable to scroll(horizontally) the list.

How can i horizontally scroll the list when the contents in the list are larger in width.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `div`s with relative width instead of `table`. Since Sencha generate divs which doesn't work very well with tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scrollable: {
        direction: 'both',
        directionLock: true
},
```